# Roguelike FOV problem

Tags: c++, roguelike

I am working on a college compsci project and I would like some help with a field of view algorithm. I works mostly, but in some situations the algorithm sees through walls and hilights walls the player should not be able to see.

```
void cMap::los(int x0, int y0, int radius)
{ //Does line of sight from any particular tile

for(int x = 0; x < m_Height; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < m_Width; y++) {
        getTile(x,y)->setVisible(false);
    }
}

double  xdif = 0;
double  ydif = 0;
bool    visible = false;
float   dist = 0;

for (int x = MAX(x0 - radius,0); x < MIN(x0 + radius, m_Height); x++) {      //Loops through x values within view radius
    for (int y = MAX(y0 - radius,0); y < MIN(y0 + radius, m_Width); y++) {         //Loops through y values within view radius

        xdif = pow( (double) x - x0, 2);
        ydif = pow( (double) y - y0, 2);

        dist = (float) sqrt(xdif + ydif); //Gets the distance between the two points

        if (dist <= radius) {               //If the tile is within view distance,
            visible = line(x0, y0, x, y);       //check if it can be seen.

            if (visible) {                          //If it can be seen,
                getTile(x,y)->setVisible(true);        //Mark that tile as viewable
            }
        }
    }   
}
}

bool cMap::line(int x0,int y0,int x1,int y1)
{
bool steep = abs(y1-y0) > abs(x1-x0);

if (steep) {
    swap(x0, y0);
    swap(x1, y1);
}

if (x0 > x1) {
    swap(x0,x1);
    swap(y0,y1);
}

  int deltax = x1-x0;
  int deltay = abs(y1-y0);
  int error = deltax/2;
  int ystep;
  int y = y0;

  if (y0 < y1)
     ystep = 1;
  else
     ystep = -1;

  for (int x = x0; x < x1; x++) {

      if ( steep && getTile(y,x)->isBlocked()) {
          getTile(y,x)->setVisible(true);
          getTile(y,x)->setDiscovered(true);
        return false;
      } else if (!steep && getTile(x,y)->isBlocked()) {
          getTile(x,y)->setVisible(true);
          getTile(x,y)->setDiscovered(true);
        return false;
      }

     error -= deltay;

     if (error < 0) {
        y = y + ystep;
        error = error + deltax;
     }

  }

  return true;
}
```

If anyone could help me make the first blocked tiles visible but stops the rest, I would appreciate it.

thanks,
Manderin87

Comment: Should probably move this over to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not necessarily. He has a problem with an algorithm. It matters not what application uses it.

Comment: Not an answer but a comment on the code: it is a good idea to be setting 'visible' and 'discovered' flags in line() and los()? That could be making your debugging harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be attempting to create a raycasting algorithm. I assume you have knowledge of how Bresenham's lines work, so I'll cut to the chase.

Instead of checking the visibility of each cell in the potential field of view, you only need to launch Bresenham lines from the FOV centre towards each cell at the very perimetre of the potential FOV area (the square you loop through). At each step of the Bresenham line, you check the cell status. The pseudocode for each ray would go like this:

```
while (current_cell != destination) {
    current_cell.visible = true;
    if (current_cell.opaque) break;
    else current_cell = current_cell.next();
}
```

Please remember that raycasting produces tons of artifacts and you might also need postprocessing after you have calculated your field of view.

Some useful resources:

- [ray casting on Roguebasin](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=Ray_casting)
- [ray casting FOV implementation](http://doryen.eptalys.net/svn-libtcod/trunk/src/fov_circular_raycasting.c) in [libtcod](http://doryen.eptalys.net/libtcod/) (in C, you can dig through the repository for a C++ wrapper to it)
- [a FOV study](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=Comparative_study_of_field_of_view_algorithms_for_2D_grid_based_worlds)

Comment: Gah, stole my Rougebasin thunder! :)

Comment: I think the problem is the line is skipping past the walls closest to the player because it only happens on a diagonal. I'm unsure of how to fix it.

Comment: Last link is broken.

Comment: @JoePerkins thanks for the heads up. I removed it as it's permanently dead.